# Check if an Activity was triggered by a particular Activity

Tags: android

Is it possible to check that an Activity was triggered by a particular Activity.

For example, I have 2 Activities, Activity A and Activity B and A triggered B using an Intent. And now that I am in Activity B, I want to check that Activity B was triggered by Activity A, like:

if(Activity B was trigger by Activity A)
{
  //do something
}

Comment: Please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) an answer if one of them helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
getCallingActivity();
```

to get the name of the activity that started the current activity. But you should consider why you need this functionality. Most activities should be loose coupled.

Comment: "Note: if the calling activity is not expecting a result (that is it did not use the startActivityForResult(Intent, int) form that includes a request code), then the calling package will be null."

Answer (score 1):

When creating the Intent, you can pass some information, such as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("com.mypackage.triggeredby", "ActivityA");
```

And in ActivityB's onCreate or onResume, you then say:

```
Intent data = getIntent();
triggeredBy = data.getStringExtra("com.mypackage.triggeredby");
```

I like Strings, but you could alternately pass the Object, or an int, or anything you can use to identify it with.

Comment: If you are going to go through the trouble of putting the calling activity in the intent, you might as well save yourself some code and just change startActivity to startActivityForResult, even if no result is expected. Either way, its on the calling activity to allow the called activity to know who it is.